# tinyMCE IE white space bug

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using the newest version of tinyMCE 4.1.5 on my site, and on IE, if I press (with the mouse) on the wrong place (usually the bottom) to select it, it "ignores" spaces and "enters" until I press Ctrl+A and delete.

How can I solve it?

***EDIT:***
Found out that the `body` if the `iframe` the tinyMCE uses, is not the same height as the parent `div`, but it looks a one block.

If I press the area between the `div` and `body`, the but occurs (not sure that's the only place).

Comment: Press what? To select what? What is the "wrong place"? What version of IE are you using?

Comment: Edited and answered your questions @Teemu. Thanks!

Comment: Except the IE version. Make sure you're running IE in edge mode, i.e. there's proper DTD at the beginning of the file, and compatibility mode is not used.

Comment: I run it on IE 8 mode, since my users use IE8

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Found out when giving the RTE body a border "1px solid white" the problem is gone.